# Who was Star Trek: The Next Generation’s floral designer?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I love a lot of the floral arrangements seen in TNG, and I was wondering if anyone knows who designed these arrangements?  There is one in particular, in S3:E18 "Sins of the Father" near the beginning of the episode when the Enterprise crew is treating Klingon Commander Kern to dinner, that I love.

[image]

I've looked through all of the set designers etc. for that episode, and I have yet to find any information about the floral arrangements specifically.  It would be great to find out who did the arrangements, so I could see if they've done any other work.

Comment: http://sharetv.com/shows/journeys_end_the_saga_of_star_trek_the_next_generation/cast/richard_d_james

Comment: That is nice. [A *warrior’s* bouquet!](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Prune_juice)

Comment: Oh that was @Valorum. I usually stick to adding facetious comments.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - In fairness, we both do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to IMDB for that episode, there was no dedicated florist in the credits. The Set Decoration for that episode was done by Jim Mees.

According to the [Next Generation Companion](https://books.google.com/books?id=VTifVpk6cekC&pg=PT365&lpg=PT365&dq=Jim+Mees+floral+star+trek&source=bl&ots=VZU7HF8WGB&sig=HTCyuuCbCLWT02FnYKlTJkbmAcs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ8raQjI_XAhUH5oMKHeW1BSAQ6AEIUDAK#v=onepage&q=Jim%20Mees%20floral%20star%20trek&f=false), Jim Mees was responsible for the floral arrangements in other episodes including [Sub Rosa](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sub_Rosa_(episode)) so it's not unreasonable that he did the floral arrangements in that episode.

> Set decorator Jim Mees recalled having to come up with a room full of camelias a month out of their season.

Comment: Sorry, but this **doesn't answer the question asked**. We know who the set decorator is, but it's pretty likely that they bought in the the centrepiece from somewhere/someone else. Also, how do you know that it didn't fall to Set Designer Richard James to sort out the floral arrangements?

Comment: According to the [Next Generation Companion](https://books.google.com/books?id=VTifVpk6cekC&pg=PT365&lpg=PT365&dq=Jim+Mees+floral+star+trek&source=bl&ots=VZU7HF8WGB&sig=HTCyuuCbCLWT02FnYKlTJkbmAcs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ8raQjI_XAhUH5oMKHeW1BSAQ6AEIUDAK#v=onepage&q=Jim%20Mees%20floral%20star%20trek&f=false), Jim Mees was responsible for the floral arrangements in other episodes including *Sub Rosa* so it's not unreasonable that he did the floral arrangements in other episodes unless otherwise noted; however that's a guess and not really an answer.

Comment: There is always a mention in the credits for guest appearances and contractors. If there was a specific person brought in they would have been reference. Floral design is one of the many things that is under the responsibility of a Set Decorator. @Valorum my answer is valid, because Jim Mees is the Set Decorator, and has done floral designs on other sets.

Comment: @MarkBeadles - Now *that* would make an excellent basis for an answer.

Comment: @as.beaulieu - The question is who "*did the arrangement"*, not who had overall responsibility. You might as well have listed the producer or the studio

Comment: @Valorum I will edit this answer to include that information, as.beaulieu can have the upvotes.